# Ember.js Route with Wildcard Path

Tags: ember.js

How can I make a route that servers all paths? I tried `this.route('main', {path: '/*'});` with no luck. I can't use dynamic segments because I want `/random`, `/random/random`, etc. to all route to `main`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a catch all route like this.

```
Router.map(function() {     
  this.route('main', {
    path: '/*path'
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the link-to helper with wildcard paths? `{{#link-to 'test' tagName='li'}}` errors: "Uncaught Error: There is no route named test"

Comment: The wildcard route is called `main`  `{{#link-to 'main' tagName='li'}}`

Comment: Yes but I need to do `{{#link-to 'main.test1' tagName='li'}}`, `{{#link-to 'main.test2' tagName='li'}}`, etc. But I receive "Uncaught Error: There is no route named main.test1", "Uncaught Error: There is no route named main.test2", etc.